# How to modify environment variables (such as PATH) when using python.unittest in VS Code?

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, environment-variables

I'm writing a python unit test using `unittest` and I want to compile some Solidity contracts in the test setup.

However, when I did the compile by `os.system()` or `subprocess.run()`, it shows that `solc`, the Solidity compiler, not found. While it runs properly when running in a non-test python program.

After this happens, I found a further interesting things: when I `print(os.environ)` in both a test python program using unittest and a normal python program, the result is of hugh difference! Including the most important one: `$PATH`. It looks like the following:

```
****PATH in unittest****
/usr/bin
/usr/local/bin
...(mostly the default $PATH set by Linux)


****PATH in normal program****
/usr/bin
/.../myEnvs/.../bin
...(as same as my console's $PATH, which is exported in .bashrc)
```

Since I'm working with others to develop this program, I should NOT add path such as "myEnvs" in program (by using environment setting like `env=` parameter provided by subprocess.Popen()).

I think the abnormal `$PATH` in python.unittest is caused by some configurations introduced by VScode, so what are these configs? How could I modify them? or this `"PATH inconsistence"` is caused by some other reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey.....   After a period of time, I finally find out what happens:

1. Exactly, The so-called "`$PATH` difference" is caused by VScode configurations in launch.json.
2. You can create a new term like this and make your unittest configuration same as a normal debug:

````
{
    ...
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal", 
            "justMyCode": false,
            "args": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Debug Tests",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "purpose": ["debug-test"],
            "console": "integratedTerminal", // Consistence with ```Python: CurrentFile```
            "justMyCode": false,
        },
    ]
}
````

3. This `Debug Test` configuration can be used in different test mode, see more in [VSCode doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing) - Debug tests.
4. The critial one is "console", the default value is "internalConsole", which seems to share the same `env` with system defaults. While I should set it to "integratedTerminal", which is consistent with my own shell.